# Double click text selection in CFEclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, coldfusion, cfeclipse

In CFEclipse, I do a lot of double-clicking to select text. The standard behavior is to select all text within the nearest *word boundaries*. This is problematic when editing code where the original editor didn't use camel-case; for example, they wrote "myObject" as "my_object".

Is there a way to change the double-click selection behavior to include '_' as a valid *word* character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CFEclipse does not recognize either the underscore or a period as a character for selecting text with a double-click.  There is no way that I know of other than rolling your sleeves up and hacking the editor code to change it.  I doubt that this will be changed any time soon with the impending release of Bolt from Adobe.

Answer (score 7):

In the latest version of CFEclipse, there is now the option to define what characters are considered word boundaries when double-clicking, and also the option to use different characters when using alt or shift keys.

In Preferences, goto CFEclipse > Editor > Text Selection to update this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [bpsite.net](https://bpsite.net/misc/eclipse_text-selection.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

On eclipse 3.4.1 Ganymede, it seems to select the nearest boundaries *including* the '_' (at least in the java file I am using)

What eclipse version are you using ?

This [blog](http://blog.jonschneider.com/2008/07/don-treat-underscore-as-word-separator.html) even reports that eclipse3.3 does select word as you are expecting it...

[image: Notepad2] vs. [image: FireFox]

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I was using the CFEclipse plugin for ColdFusion development